# Meteor file modified refresh taking 2 minutes

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am having a big problem with meteor. Build process "meteor run" is extremely slow it takes about 10 minutes but that is not the bad part since it only happens once when starting.

The bad part is that it takes ~2 minutes to show my changes, file changed watcher taking too long.

When working with a basic example the feedback was way better ~5 seconds and it was workable but now that I am working on a real project it is impossible to make any progress.

I have around 40 packages in packages file and I am using latest meteor (1.3.2.4 at this time).

There were a ton of questions around this problem [#4284](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284) [#6750](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6750), I don't know if there is any tip to bypass this issue ( changing any config,adding more RAM or anything ).

It there is no solution of that it would be helpful if there is a way to limit file watch to only a certain folder at a moment.

**Update:** I noticed there is ".node_modules" in the root of app can it be excluded from build process?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Webpack](https://atmospherejs.com/webpack/webpack) for Meteor.

It supports hot module reload, which can shorten rebuild times a lot. There are some differences compared to the default build process, so you'll need to learn a thing or two about it, but it could be well worth your time.

Try it by fetching [kickstart-meteor-react-flowrouter](https://github.com/thereactivestack/kickstart-meteor-react-flowrouter) from GitHub.